# null value when fetch image from json data using picasso

Tags: java, android, json

I'v tried to create a movies app so I create recycleview to display the poster in gridlayout using networking with api json data
now the app fetch the name of movies and it's popularity without problems but can't fetch the poster and when I debug the app I found the value of poster null when it comes to onbindviewholder why that?

this is the adapter of recycleview:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<MovieItem> mMoviesItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter() {

    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView MoviePopularity;
        public final ImageView MoviePoster;
        public final TextView MovieName;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            MoviePopularity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_popularity);
            MoviePoster = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_movie);
            MovieName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.movie_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.MoviePopularity.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getPopularity()));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(mMoviesItems.get(position).getPhoto()).into(holder.MoviePoster);
        holder.MovieName.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getName()));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mMoviesItems)
            return 0;
        else {
            return mMoviesItems.size();
        }
    }

    public void setMovieData(ArrayList<MovieItem> movieData) {
        mMoviesItems = movieData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

and this is the custom class:

```
public class MovieItem {
    private double popularity;
    private String photo;
    private String name;

    public MovieItem(double popularity, String poster_path, String original_title) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.photo = poster_path;
        this.name = original_title;
    }

    public double getPopularity() { return popularity; }
    public String getPhoto() { return photo; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

and this is the json class:
    public final class OpenMovieJsonUtils {

```
    public static ArrayList<MovieItem> getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(Context context, String moviesJsonString)
            throws JSONException {

        final String RESULTS = "results";
        final String POPULARITY = "popularity";
        final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";

        ArrayList<MovieItem> parsedMovieData = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();

        JSONObject moviesObject = new JSONObject(moviesJsonString);
        JSONArray moviesArray = moviesObject.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {
            double popularity;
            String poster_path;
            String original_title;

            moviesObject = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            popularity = moviesObject.getDouble(POPULARITY);
            poster_path = moviesObject.getString(POSTER_PATH);
            original_title = moviesObject.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);

            parsedMovieData.add(new MovieItem(popularity, poster_path, original_title));

        }

        return parsedMovieData;
    }
}
```

this is the networking class:

```
public final class NetworkUtils {

    private static final String TAG = NetworkUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String MOVIES_BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
    private static final String MOVIES_URL  = MOVIES_BASE_URL;
    private static final String apiKey = "36666cbb5d7e20041e705d1b2c4e7a79";

    final static String API_PARAM = "api_key";

    public static URL buildUrl(String MoviesQuery) {
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MOVIES_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendPath(MoviesQuery)
                .appendQueryParameter(API_PARAM, apiKey)
                .build();

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Built URI " + url);
        return url;
    }

    public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong with images so I get their values null instead of the popularity and name of movies works and not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is incomplete, doesn't specify the complete details about from where you are getting API response.

I could answer this question because I have just done this project in my ongoing Android Developer Nanodegree by Udacity.

Hopefully you are fetching the movie details from TMDB.

You should read the Project implementation guide thoroughly which says

> You will need to append a base path ahead of this relative path to build the complete url you will need to fetch the image using Picasso

Following code will help you -

```
public class MovieItem {
    private double popularity;
    private String photo;
    private String name;

    public MovieItem(double popularity, String poster_path, String original_title) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.photo = poster_path;
        this.name = original_title;
    }

    public double getPopularity() { return popularity; }
    public String getPhoto() { return photo; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public Uri getFullPosterPath() {
        return Uri.parse("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendPath("w185")
                .appendEncodedPath(getPhoto())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And in Adapter make this change -

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.MoviePopularity.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getPopularity()));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(mMoviesItems.get(position).getFullPosterPath()).into(holder.MoviePoster);
        holder.MovieName.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getName()));
    }
```

Comment: sorry because my questions it's not clear, now I edit the question and add at the end the class of networking you can see it, then yes write I use the TMDB and I'm a nanodegree student at udacity
I'm going to do the changes you write it here and back to you

Comment: thanks a lot man I tried it now it works perfect you saved my day